# JavaScript - array of objects, etc

Tags: javascript

Say I have the following:

```
var a = '1',
    b = 'foo';
```

How do I create an object using the above variables such that my object looks like this:

```
'1' => 'foo'
```

I'm trying to make this like an associative array. Furthermore, I want `1` to contain an array of objects. I have the variable that have the array of object; I just need to put it in `1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an object literal:

```
var myObject = { "1" : "foo" };
```

or, if you want to create it from variables, create a new object then assign things.

```
var myObject = {};
myObject[a] = b;
```

> Furthermore, I want 1 to contain an array of objects

JavaScript doesn't care what type the data is. `b` can be an array as easily as a string. (And you can use an array literal where you have a string literal in the short version)

```
var myObject = { "1" : [ 7, "foo", new Date() ] };
```

Comment: +1 for posting almost exactly what I'd just typed (but obviously no longer need to post).

Comment: Keep in mind that a Javascript array is basically an object as well. So, if `var testArray = [];`, you can manipulate it with the form `testArray[0] = 1;` or `testArray['1'] = 'foo';` or even `testArray.bar = 'baz';`.

Comment: Quentin, I'm having problems assigning an object to a property in my containing object. For example: `oMyTest['1']['data'] = data;`. The variable `data` is an object.

Comment: So long as `oMyTest['1']` is an object, that should just work.

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = { '1' : 'foo' };

obj['1']; // returns 'foo'
```

or

```
var obj = { '1' : new Array() };
obj['1']; // returns an array
```

Comment: It sounds the OP wants the mirror image of the second `obj`, which I doubt would be possible.

Answer (score 0):

To do literally what you asked:

```
var a = '1',
    b = 'foo',
    o = {};

o[a] = b;
```

Quentin has the rest of the answer.

#### Edit

An example of assigning an object to an object property:

```
var foo = {bar: 'baz'};
var obj = {foo: foo};

// or 
// var obj = {};
// obj['foo'] = foo;
// or
// obj.foo = foo;

alert(obj.foo.bar); // baz
```

Comment: RobG, I need `o` to contain another object. Say I have the object `data` and want it in `o['data']` - how do I do that?